# Opposite of PathCreateFromUrl

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, winapi

I need to convert a local file path into a file protocol URL to be opened by a web browser (IE in particular.) What I need is the opposite of what [PathCreateFromUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API does. So is there such API?

Comment: Umm, I just guessed this wouldn't exist, but it did: [`UrlCreateFromPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773773(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @chris: Thanks. It says that it "does not support extended paths." There's no other one, right?

Comment: Not that I know of. I tried searching that one expecting it not to exist.

Comment: @chris: Sorry. I didn't pose this question correctly. The reason I'm asking is because I don't really like using APIs that work in 90% of the times. If I find another API I'll post it here...